# BashOperator dosen't run bash file requires SUDO privileges

Tags: python, airflow

i have script called CC that collects the data and push it into a data warehouse .
I created a dag for it

```
      Task_I = BashOperator(
        task_id="CC",
        run_as_user="koa",
        bash_command="sudo /home/koa/CC"
      )
```

and I've added the permission to run it without typing password by modifying  /etc/sudoers

```
  koa ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/koa/CC
```

however when the task fails in airflow and the log states that a password is needed

```
{bash_operator.py:146} INFO - Running command: sudo /home/koa/CC 
{bash_operator.py:153} INFO - Output:
{bash_operator.py:157} INFO - sudo: a terminal is required to read 
 the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass 
 helper
{bash_operator.py:159} INFO - Command exited with return code 1
```

It will be great if you can help me guys , i'am new to airflow and have been struggling with this for the last few hours

Comment: This is probably more of a sudo question than Airflow, but airflow makes it a little bit more confusing to work out exactly what is going on here.

Comment: Could you change the bash_command to `whoami && sudo -nl` - this might give some more clues as to what is going on.

Comment: Also a further observation: "run_as_user" is doing a sudo itself, so why not just specify `run_as_user='root'`

Comment: when i run the command  "sudo /home/koa/CC" , as my default user 'koa' ,  outside of airflow ,it works without asking for the password .

Comment: I ran the bash command with whoami && sudo -nl  and it returns this 
INFO - Running command: whoami && sudo -nl /home/koa/CC
{bash_operator.py:153} INFO - Output:
 {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - koa
{bash_operator.py:157} INFO - /home/koa/CC
{bash_operator.py:159} INFO - Command exited with return code 0